# Solution of non-linear second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working with a system, which is described by the following differential equation

$y'' = (1+y)^{3/2}$

Does this differential equation have a closed-form solution? And more generally: Is there a place, which contains a complete list of second-order differential equations, which do have analytical solutions?

Comment: Check the solution on [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27+%3D+(1%2By)%5E(3%2F2)) - it has an extremely messy solution that uses the hypergeometric function. Have you made a typo somewhere?

Comment: Anyway do you have the initial conditions or any other restriction on your system? This could make the integration a lot easier.

Comment: Boundary conditions are y(0)=0, y(L)=a.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply with $2y'$ and integrate once to get
$$
y'^2-y_0'^2 = \frac45(1+y)^{5/2}-\frac45(1+y_0)^{5/2}
$$
This gives you the curves in the phase plane that the solutions follow, any further integration leads to moderately nasty integrals,
$$
\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{y_0^2-\frac45(1+y_0)^{5/2}+\frac45(1+y)^{5/2}}}=t+C
$$

Comment: The boundary conditions are y(0)=0 and y(L)=a, where a and L are arbitrary constants.

Comment: Then you have to solve $$\int_0^a\frac{dy}{\sqrt{2E+\frac45(1+y)^{5/2}}}=L$$ for $E$, where $2E=y'^2-\frac45(1+y)^{5/2}$ is a constant of motion, you can call $E$ the energy. Which leads you into the realm of special functions